# Write the output of python in a file and load the output in another python script. (Python ver 2.6 - 2.7)

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x

Case: I have a python file which upon execution generates a output as integer which I want to write it in another file and load the generated file to another python script to execute further.

what I have tried till now:

py1:

```
import os
import json

print('Exchanges')
url_stc = os.popen("curl -u *****:*****    
https://api.exchanges.com/count").read()
data_stc = json.loads(url_stc)
if (p_count > 3):
   stc_n = p_count
   print('Stock counts are increased to:')
   print stc_n
else:
   stc_n = 3
   print stc_n

print('rates')
url_rates = os.popen("curl -u *****:*****    
https://api.exchanges.com/rates").read()
data_rates = json.loads(url_rates)
if (p_rates > 1):
   rates_n = p_rates
   print('rate counts are increased to:')
   print rates_n
else:
   rates_n = 1
   print rates_n


output: stc_n, rates_n
```

I want the output which will be a integer to be written in a file every time I execute the code a (new file) should be generated and also old file should be replaced with the new one.

py2:

```
from new file import *
def abc():
    if(stc_n == 3):
       ## do some stuff
def mnq():
    if(rates_n == 1):
       ##do some stuff
```

I am trying the same with

```
f = file("/new_file.txt",'r')
data = f.read()
if not len(data) > 4:
   variable1 = "3" # note this data is what to be returned from new file
   variable2 = "2" # note this data is what to be returned from new file
else:
   data = string.split(data,"\n") 
variable1 = int(data[0])
variable2 = int(data[1])
```

What I am missing here any clues?

Comment: what happened ?

Comment: you get errors in this code...1. print is between the if and else block. 2. where are some variable define like "p_count"

Comment: @repzero Those are typo error , It is in proper indent when I run the code.

Comment: @Shiping Output is not getting printed in a new file also the file is not being replaced in the next run and as a result when I am importing the new file it is empty.

Comment: i don't see you open a file to write the result in py1. shouldn't you need this in py1? f = open("new_file.txt", "w"), then replace print stc_n with f.write(str(stc_n) + "\n") and print rates_n with f.write(str(rates_n) + "\n")

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it is not replacing the old file everytime, as i need to execute this code both the files pi1 and py2 at every 5 minutes.
once the new file is created it is not overwritin the existing new file